# Prism - Xamarin Forms: How to keep bottom tab active during navigation

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am a xamarin forms prism app, I have 3 tabs and the tab bar is active only on that specific page, If i navigate deep inside a specific tab, the bottom tab is gone. Is there a way to keep the bottom tab active through even when we navigate to other pages inside these tabs?

I tried to do something like [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/navigation/tabbed-page) but i am not able to do it in prism.

Without prism it’s pretty straight forward to do as shown in above link but I’m not ablr todo with prism. Can anyone suggest how I can achieve it?

**MY CODE:**
**App.Xaml.cs**

```
protected override async void OnInitialized()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            await NavigationService.NavigateAsync("NavigationPage/MainPage");
        }
```

**MainPage.XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
< TabbedPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
             xmlns:ios="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.iOSSpecific;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.Core" 
             xmlns:android="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.AndroidSpecific;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.Core" 
             xmlns:windows="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.WindowsSpecific;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.Core"


             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyTabs.Common.Views"
             x:Class="MyTabs.Common.Views.MainPage" BackgroundColor="Olive" BarBackgroundColor="Maroon">
     <TabbedPage.Children>
     <local:PageOne Title="PageOne"
                         Icon="PageOne.png" />

    <local:PageTwo Title="PageTwo"
                         Icon="PageTwo.png" />

    <NavigationPage Title="PageThree" Icon="PageThree s.png">
        <x:Arguments> 
                    <local: PageThree/> 
        </x:Arguments>
        </NavigationPage>
    <local:PageFour Title="PageFour"
                         Icon="PageFour.png" />
    </TabbedPage.Children>
</TabbedPage>
```

PageThreeViewModel:

```
public class PageThreeViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        private ICommand pageFiveCommand;
        public ICommand PageFiveCommand { get { return pageFiveCommand; } }

        private void OnCloseCommand()
        {
            _navigationService.GoBackAsync();
        }

        public PageThreeCommand ViewModel()
        {
            pageFiveCommand = new DelegateCommand(OnPageFiveCommand);
        }

        private async void OnPageFiveCommand()
        {
            //await _navigationService.NavigateAsync(?NavigationPage/PageFive");
            await _navigationService.NavigateAsync("GiftCardPage");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried making the Pages inside the Tab a NavigationPage. That way the tab will stick around

Comment: How would I do that?

Comment: So only PageThree needs the navigation inside? Can you paste the code where you're navigating in Page3 to some other page? Also can you try removing the NavigationPage in await NavigationService.NavigateAsync("NavigationPage/MainPage");

Comment: All the pages need it, but currently just testing out Page three. its just a blank page. Did not add anything in that page.

Comment: You have to Navigate from PageThreeViewModel then it should work. Cause I have done the same

Comment: I added my code on pagethreeviewmodel, i am doing the same

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172742/discussion-between-absolutesith-and-thedeveloper).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by Wrapping the `ContentPage` inside the `TabbedPage` with `NavigationPage`.

***Code*** :

```
<TabbedPage>
    <TabbedPage.Children>
        <NavigationPage Title="Home" Icon="home.png">
            <x:Arguments>
                <ContentPage>
                    //Your ContentPage here
                    //You can have a ViewModel for this ContentPage and Navigate inside that and will still have the Tabbed Page outside.
                </ContentPage>
            </x:Arguments>
        </NavigationPage>
    </TabbedPage.Children>
</TabbedPage>
```

Comment: I tried the code `<x:Arguments>  <local:NewsFeed/>   </x:Arguments>` where `<local:NewsFeed/> ` is the content page but when I navigate inside NewsFeed, the tab doesn't stick at the bottom.

Comment: How are you navigating inside? Can you post the code?